# B1 Visa Status - Refused

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

My B1 visa status is showing as refused but passport status is showing as your passport is still with US Embassy/Consulate. Though Visa Officer returned by passport after the interview. He has not given me any rejection letter neither told me the reason.
Please guide me what  could be the reason!!!!

Comment: I doubt we can help with the reason for the visa refusal, since that would be speculation, but perhaps someone can help explain the inconsistency.  Where are you seeing that your passport is still with the embassy/consulate?  What did the visa officer say when returning your passport to you?

Comment: Its showing in https://cgifederal.secure.force.com/applicanthome.

Comment: Am more concerned why VO had not given me refusal letter.

Comment: Then how can i understand what was my mistake during the interview process?

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen they're not entirely useless, as they at least identify the specific law under which the applicant has been refused, and a failure to notify the applicant of the "ground(s) of ineligibility" and availability of a waiver or other mechanism to overcome the ineligibility is generally a violation of [22 CFR 41.121(b)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/41.121#b_1).

Comment: @mdd if I read the question correctly, the passport was already returned (at the end of the interview).

Comment: @phoog USA visa refusals have no details and give you about one of two or three reasons for the refusal. They're generally of very little help except to let you know you did not commit fraud.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen that is true, but returning the passport at the end of the interview as described here does not constitute a proper visa refusal and frankly strikes me as weird.  Even if the refusal letter is not particularly useful, it is in fact required by law ([8 USC 1182(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#b) unless the Secretary of State has waived that requirement under paragraph (2) or the grounds for refusal are criminal or related to security (paragraph (3)). Perhaps the answer lies there.  Deblina Sarkar, do you have a criminal history?

Comment: @phoog I am not disputing your assertion about the weirdness or legality. In fact you are right. I am just pointing out that he likely won't glean anything meaningful from it to help his next application.

Comment: @Phoog : I don't have any criminal or legal allegation.Nor do i had visited to USA earlier. This was my first interview and purpose of visit is to attend business conference.

Comment: @phoog Ah yes, I misread the question.

Comment: @DeblinaSarkar: I think you should contact the embassy directly by email or phone and ask about this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply..it is really helpful

Comment: You can reapply _ provided _ the circumstances of your case (application) _ has changed. Regards